# Get components that derive from base class c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working in a c# environment and am creating a base class and would like to have other classes like `StormyWeather.cs` or `SunnyWeather.cs` and have these classes derive from the base class `BaseWeather.cs`

```c#
public class BaseWeather: MonoBehaviour{
    public ParticleSystem particleSystem;
    public AudioClip weatherAudio;

    public string Name;
    public float AudioFadeTime = 0.25f;

    public float LightDimTime = 0.1f;
    public float MinimumIntensity = 0f;
    public float MaximumIntensity = 1f;
    public float Intensity = 0.25f;

    private void Start(){
        particleSystem.enableEmission = false;
    }

    public virtual void Weather (){
        if (WeatherSystem.Instance._debugState == DebugLevel.Full) {
            Debug.Log (Name + " Starting at: " + Time.timeSinceLevelLoad);
        }

        particleSystem.enableEmission = true;
    }
}
```

So in turn the `SunnyWeather.cs` might look like this

```c#
public class SunnyWeather : BaseWeather {
    public override void Weather(){
        base.Weather ();
    }
}
```

How do I look/get the first script on a gameobject that derives from the `BaseWeather.cs`

To clarify I am using unity and the `SunnyWeather.cs` will be attached to a gameObject I would like to know how I find the **First Component** on a gameObject that is inherited(for a better term) from the `BaseWeather.cs` class

The reason for this is I will have multiple scripts for each weather like `SunyWeather.cs, StormWeather.cs, SnowWeather.cs` and they all derive from the `BaseWeather.cs` class

EDIT:

I am currently using this to call it but do not know if it is the right way to do so
`GetComponent<BaseWeather>().Weather();`

Comment: Names starting with "I" refers normally to Interfaces, but in your case IWeatherState seems to be normal class.

Comment: I can't understand the question.

Comment: When I first started making it i had planned for it to be an interface(really need to fix that) but I kept moving forward with the code once I realized an interface wasnt gonna work

Comment: I updated the question hope it clarifys for you @ZoharPeled

Comment: You're currently doing it the right way but your naming convention is wrong. `I` in front of class name indicates that it's an interface and you've just made a base class. It would be better to call it a `BaseWeather` or something similar.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect that change @m.rogalski

Comment: I don't think this is detailed enough for an answer, but in short: **YES** this should work fine. `GetComponent` will work with inherited classes too. If you never use `BaseWeather` itself, I'd even make it `abstract`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer most of your concerns I could say that yes, you're currently doing it the right way but **only if it fits your needs**.

`GetComponent` will return the first component that matches your query which in that case is type assignable by the component type. Meaning that if you put the base class in your query, it will return you the first occurrence of the type that derives or is that type.

To ensure that's the right component you can place it on top of other components using inspector view or filter it out by calling `GetComponents` and then iterate through all of the matching components.

---

Shortening my answer, if you have more than one `BaseWeather` component you should use `GetComponents<BaseWeather>` method and filter out the one you want in any other case just use `GetComponent<BaseWeather>` method.

Comment: Thanks I wasnt sure if `GetComponent<BaseClass>()` would grab the derived script or just get the `BaseClass` thanks fr clearing that up

Comment: @FlamingGenius Just remember to properly mark methods/properties as virtual or abstract and you should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

If I understood the question, you can identify the inheritance using:

```
    (from assemblies in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        from types in assemblies.GetTypes()
        where typeof(IWeatherState).IsAssignableFrom(types)
        select types
    ).ToArray();
```

But, to you get the First, you will need to do something hardcoding, like a Queue or Stack.

Comment: The answer you provided would answer the question *"How can I find all types in all loaded assemblies that inherit from (or are assignable to) IWeatherState?"*. That however, wasn't the question.